# Jar file name problems in persistence.xml

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa

We have a maven build that creates an ear file that includes libraries with JPA entities in its internal `lib` folder. The ear file has one `persistence.xml`, where we add the entities using the `<jar-file>` tag:

```
<persistence-unit name="some-id">
    <jar-file>MyEntities-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar-file>
```

The `MyEntities` lib is build with a separate maven project.

This works fine as long as the build is done locally, iaw, I only use `mvn install` and do not deploy to a remote snapshot repository. It fails, when we start deploying to a repo because of  different jar file names in the local `.m2` repo and the remote repo:

`mvn install` creates a file named `MyEntities-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` on the local repo, `mvn deploy` a file named `MyEntities-1.0.0-20131212-145600-42.jar` on the remote repository.

Now, if someone deployed after my last local build and maven looks for new snapshot updates (policy based or with `-U` flag), it pulls the remote file to the local repo and the jar with THAT name is copied to the ear, which causes JPA errors at deploy time because the entities can't be found (different jar file declared in persistence.xml).

Is there a solution to that problem apart from always building locally before assembling the ear file?

Comment: I think you should check the documentation of the deploy-plugin... See this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html and search for the -Dfile parameter.

Comment: Don't like that approach, because it changes the naming convention of deployed snapshot artifacts. Plus I'd run into troubles when bumping version numbers or releasing - because now I'd have the version number set in the parameters of the deploy plugin.

Comment: Just speculating: do you still have the same problem if you do a ´mvn clean´ before the ´mvn deploy`?

Comment: @AndreiI - sure, the trouble starts when maven resolves snapshot dependencies. If the latest version has been build locally, everything's fine. If the latest is found on the remote repo, then I get one with a filename that doesn't match the name declared on the persistence.xml

Comment: @Andreas_D did you ever found the solution? I think i'm going to set a placeholder in the persistence.xml and filter the file before building

Comment: @Michel - no, sorry, I can't remember that we ever solved that (on that project, it's quite long ago)

Answer (score 0):

This works for our project:

```
<persistence-unit name="foo">
    <!-- property comes from root pom.xml -->
    <jar-file>../lib/foo-${bar.version}.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
 <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>META-INF/persistence.xml</include>
                </includes>
         </resource>
     </resources>
</build>
```